# mongoose fetch posts by user and by his followings

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

How to fetch posts by user and all his followings posts (Mongodb, Mongoose, Nodejs)

User Schema

```
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    firstName: { type: String, required: true, trim: true },
    lastName: { type: String, required: true, trim: true },
});
userSchema.set('timestamps', true);

export default mongoose.model('user', userSchema);
```

Followers Schema

```
const followSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    follower: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'user' },
    following: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'user' },
    status: { type: Boolean, default: true }
});
followSchema.set('timestamps', true);

export default mongoose.model('follow', followSchema);
```

Posts Schema

```
const postSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    userId: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'user' },
    contents: { type: String, trim: true },
    photo: { type: String }
});
postSchema.set('timestamps', true);

export default mongoose.model('post', postSchema);
```

Thank you in advance! :)

Comment: Unclear what you are asking. Try to explain bit more

Comment: @AnthonyWinzlet Let me explain with example 
consider we have 3 users A, B & C, A following both B & C, Now i want to fetch all posts from posts collections but the posts that is done by A and also B & C because A is following B & C. let me know. if it is again unclear.

Comment: Ok so you want to get all the posts which is either created by user A or its following? what is you mongodb version? could you post some sample data

Comment: @AnthonyWinzlet Yes exactly! mongodb version --- MongoDB version v4.0.5. and what sample data you need please explain? just that follow schema contain both users ids i mean the user himself is the follower and the other is following.

Comment: @spyro i am already reading docs but did not found solution yet, but still continue anyway thanks for your help!

Comment: @spyro stackover flow is the place where  people ask question when they gets stuck. If all the things can be done  by the documentation then I think there is no need of these types of  Q&A sites

Comment: @AnthonyWinzlet fully agree with you. But there are cases where questions are better off with reading up things first. This question is perfectly answer with this: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html

Comment: @spyro then you should have recommended him before instead of advising me.

Comment: @AnthonyWinzlet "could", not "should". It's a "nice" thing to try to, gently and mannered, show people, who are trying to code, that they are, in the end, far better of with researching stuff themself than asking very broad and basic questions here. This sure is an awesome place for asking questions, but you don't need to copy-paste basic documentation a hundred times a week. Documentation is updated to new features or regarding deprecated features. Our answeres here won't. So asking too broad questions doesn't help "the community" in the end :/

Comment: @spyro are you sure my problem can be solved with your link populate? do you think i don't know about populate? if you deeply match my requirements with your provided link i think you will get my point or maybe i am wrong. i think it can be done with aggregate.lookup and i am already trying. and you guyz are helping i appreciate that. :)

Comment: @spyro btw i am looking to populate deeply!

Comment: Hmm.... are you using the followSchema because you are thinking of the usecase of more than 1 million followers per user? Because otherwiese there would be a better schema-design. Just curious now, maybe i got your usecase wrong (sorry in that case) :)

Comment: @spyro its social type of app so could be such number of people :)

Comment: Yeah, so my guess was right :) I updated my previous answer, can you have a look and see if that works for you? It shouldn't be a very unperformant answer, though in theory there might be an even more performant query. But well, doing it in 3 steps give you also the opportunity to for example limit some posts or fill in other middleware =)

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, got your question wrong.

There might be a better solution but what you should be able to do is this:

(this gets the posts of the people that are following your original user. If you did mean it the other way around, just switch :) )

```
// get the user's posts:
var theUserPosts = await postSchema.find({userId: userData._id}).exec();

// get the follower-IDs:
var theFollowersIDs = await followSchema.find({follower: userData._id, status: true}, 'following').exec();

// get the posts of those followers:
var followerPosts = await postSchema.find({userId: {$in: theFollowersIDs}}).exec();
```

Can you try this and tell us if this works for you?

Comment: okay i am thinking about your answer and if this helped i will let you know. thanks again :)

Answer (score 0):

Hy Alamghir its happy to see you here and sorry that you still did not get the answer what i can suggest you after seeing your schema that i think there is no need to create three collections you only need 2 schema first one

```
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  firstName: { type: String, required: true, trim: true },
  lastName: { type: String, required: true, trim: true },
  followers:[]
});
userSchema.set('timestamps', true);

export default mongoose.model('user', userSchema);
```

Now in followers array just push the ids of users who followed this user Now it would be very easy for you to get posts done by these people like this let suppose you have user data in `userData` variable now you can do this

```
db.postSchema.find($or:[{userId:userData._id},{userId:$in:userData.followers}])
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Trying to get what you have suggested, i'll let you know if it helped me :)

Comment: Beware. I was thinking the same but what you (@mzparacha) wrote is a mongodb-antipattern. the array of followers will grow out of bounds and will reach the document-size-limit in mongodb (16 MB). So you can at least store around 1.300.000 follower-Object-IDs in that array but then the limit is reached. And since we are talking of "followers", 1 million doesn't seems a hughe number :/

Comment: Thanks @spyro you are saying right i did not consider that it will effect the application in future i think Alamghir you were doing it right just use the populate if it did not help let me know i will suggest you some other solution

Comment: @mzparacha you normally don't think of these kind of scenarios unless you are working with such hughe numbers. Since i AM working with hughe numbers in my job, this awareness is always present on my mind^^

Answer (score 0):

You need use `$graphLookup` aggregation for get suggestion users

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).